# Calculating retention (or finding whether one record from a set exists in another)

Tags: sql, r

I'm using SQL to get data from `SQL Server` and processing it in `R`. I could use either to solve my problem.

Here's my data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2), FY = c(2010, 2008, 2009, 2011, 2009), sales = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)), .Names = c("id", "FY", "sales"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

i called it test

```
 id FY   sales
 1 2010   100
 2 2008   200
 3 2009   300
 1 2011   400
 2 2009   500
```

EDIT: What I would like to find is customer retention i.e. who bought in 2008 and also in 2009; who bought in 2009 and also in 2010; who bought in 2010 and also in 2011.

The end result grid will put 1 or non-null value in the year where the customer was retained for next year.

The end result that I'm trying to get will look like this:

```
id 2008 2009 2010 2011
1               1     
2     1
```

Using this type of table, I can calculate retention percentages for every year.

Now, I can write various `CASE` statements and sub-queries to create such a grid, but I've more than 10 years in my actual data and I would hate to hard code all the years. Perhaps, it is easier to do this in `R` once the data is `cast`, but I'm having difficult time coding this.

Comment: @shujaa hm. I don't want to say that I want zeros when there are no matches even NAs or Nulls are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tbl <- xtabs( ~ id+FY, data=test)  #......
tbl
```

So that's the positive sales and you want the ones where successive years are 1:

```
 0+( tbl[ , -1]==1 & tbl[,-ncol(tbl)]==1)
#-------
   FY
id  2009 2010 2011
  1    0    0    1
  2    1    0    0
  3    0    0    0
```

The logical operations will produce a matrix of TRUEs and FALSEs and adding 0 to a logical converts it to 0/1. I've noticed the difference in this result and think it is more acceptable. Your labeling might suggest we could see into the future. If you disagree you could use the revese since the column labels are taken from the first argument:

```
0+( tbl[,-ncol(tbl)]==1 &tbl[ , -1]==1)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm sorry I should have added more explanation. I'd like to find which customers bought two consecutive years to calculate customer retention. For example, id 1 bought in 2010 and 2011, so id 1 was retained in year 2010. and id 2 was retained in 2008.

Comment: Ah. Then you need to be looking at some further processing of that table or use `tapply`. I'll take a look.

Comment: that's awesome! I figured there had to be some column comparison way.

Answer (score 0):

The following is one way to do a pivot (using aggregation):

```
select id,
       p2008 * p2009 as [2008],
       p2009 * p2010 as [2009],
       p2010 * p2011 as [2010],
       p2011 * p2012 as [2011]
from (select t.*,
             (case when FY = 2008 then 1 end) as p2008,
             (case when FY = 2009 then 1 end) as p2009,
             (case when FY = 2010 then 1 end) as p2010,
             (case when FY = 2011 then 1 end) as p2011,
             (case when FY = 2012 then 1 end) as p2012
      from test t
     ) t
group by id
```

If you are interested in doing such retention analysis, you should learn about survival analysis, particularly recurrent event analysis.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, I can use such a query, but I don't want to hard-code year values, since they will change next year. I'd like the columns names be derived every time I run the query.

Answer (score 0):

My own ugly hack:

```
    require('sqldf')
    require('plyr')

    test_returning <- ddply(test, .(FY), function(df) { 
      cur_fy <- unique(df$FY)
      q1 <- 'select count(1) as returning from df'
      q2 <- paste('where exists (select 0 from test t where t.id = df.id and t.FY = ', cur_fy + 1, ")", sep = " ")
      qry <- paste(q1, q2, sep = " ")
      sqldf(qry)
    })

    test_total <- ddply(test, .(FY), summarize, total = length(id))
    test_retention <- merge(test_returning, test_total, all.y = TRUE)
    test_retention$retpct <- with(test_retention, returning/total)
```